# Case when with subquery

Tags: sql, syntax-error, case

I'm trying to create a query that flags every line item that falls into a list of loan numbers that i'm pulling together with a subquery.

So far my script is written as follows:

```
case when loannumber in 
    (
        select distinct cast(loannumber as float)
        from tbl_one
            where exists (select a.loannumber,
            case when a.FlagA = 0 and b.[NFC] = 'N/A' then 'x'
                    when a.FlagA = 0 and b.[NFC] <> 'N/A' and sum(a.Amount) > b.[NFC] then 'x'
                    when a.FlagA = 1 and b.[FC] = 'on approval' then 'x'
                    when a.FlagA = 1 and b.[FC] <> 'on approval' and sum(a.Amount) > b.[FC]then 'x'
                end as [error flag]
            from tbl_one a
            inner join lkp_table b
            on a.State = b.state
            group by a.loannumber, FlagA, [NFC], [FC])
    )
    then 'Error 1' else null end as [Error 1],
```

When I run the subquery, it correctly identifies all loan numbers that should be flagged, but when I put it into the case when statement, it ends up flagging every loan number in the population. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: No need for DISTINCT in sub-query - and why the group by? IN float seems a bit risky.

Comment: You should not be using `float` data types with `IN` or `=`.